# count similar rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I want to count number of similar rows in Pandas dataframe, and add it as a new column of 'count'.

For example:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  0  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  1  1  0
```

Should result in:

```
   A  B  C  D  count
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1  0  2
3  1  1  1  0  2
```

Comment: is the real data only 0/1s? If not can you give an example (this impacts potential solutions)

Comment: It's an example. Doesn't have to be 0,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to `groupby` on all columns and get the group size:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(list(df.columns))['A'].transform('size')
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  D  count
0  1  1  1  1      1
1  1  1  0  1      1
2  1  1  1  0      2
3  1  1  1  0      2
```

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'C': [1, 0, 1, 1],
                   'D': [1, 1, 0, 0]})
```

Comment: Actually it gave me:
3  1
  3
    3`

Comment: @can you double check? Works fine with the provided example. Can you test on the example dataframe from my answer?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your dataset, can you provide your dataframe as dictionary? (`df.to_dict('list')`)

Comment: @mozway Neat! What does converting `df.columns` to a list do?

Comment: @Ben this ensures the list is interpreted as the column names and not an index/grouper which shouldn't work.